# I want a command that makes all my dogs in the server stand at one point

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want the command which makes all the loaded dogs stand at one point. I have tried many things, but it won't work. I want it for PvP, and I have them all tamed.

How do I make all the loaded dogs stand at one point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the data of every wolf to be standing.
i.e. Sitting to false.

```
/execute as @e[type=wolf] run data modify entity @s Sitting set value 0
```

To modify only your own wolves u can use the nbt selector and set the Owner to your own UUID.

This will modify all wolves owned by the player with the UUID of [I; -2075515819, 1863385350, -1758723883, 2055265572].

```
/execute as @e[type=wolf,nbt={Owner:[I;-2075515819,1863385350,-1758723883, 2055265572]}] run data modify entity @s Sitting set value 0
```