# How to make all dogs stand up in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know that the command

```
/execute as @e[type=wolf] run data merge entity @s {Sitting:1b}
```

will make all dogs loaded in sit down, but is there a command to make them all stand up at once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want a command that makes all my dogs in the server stand at one point](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386944/i-want-a-command-that-makes-all-my-dogs-in-the-server-stand-at-one-point)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically `/execute as @e[type=wolf] run data merge entity @s {Sitting:0b}` should work - (`0b` means false and `1b` means true).

Edit: this does work. You can finally make your dreams of twerking dogs in Minecraft come true.